# Spring-boot - Parameterized Test - Access Application.properties in MethodSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

When writing a `ParameterizedTest` with spring-boot, one can specify a `MethodSource` which provides the values. The `MethodSource` is a static method, which means accessing autowired values and members is not possible.

I do define a value in the `application.properties` which is crucial for setting up the parameters(it points to the directory containing the data I need). How can I access the value within the static method?

example code:

application.properties:

```
com.example.directorypath=a/b/c
```

ApplicationTest:

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RdxApplicationTests {

    @Value("${com.example.directorypath}")
    private String directory;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("provideDirectories")
    public void test(File dir){
        System.out.println(dir);
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> provideDirectories(){
        //here is the place I need the value
        File f = new File(directory);

        return Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(f.listFiles())).map(Arguments::of);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to resolve the problem of static factory methods is the following:

Annotate the test class with `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` which allows factory methods within the test class to not be static.

The annotation is a JUnit5 annotation.

Source: [MethodSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource)